# Why do I to have prefix all my route handlers

Tags: node.js, express, iisnode

I'm creating an application using **Expressjs** running on **node** under **IISNode** (i.e on windows).

I start by setting things up very much like all the **expressjs** examples I've seen:

```
  backend.configure(function() {
    backend.register('html', {
      compile: function(str, options) {
        return function(locals) {
          return str;
        };
      }
    });
    backend.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    backend.set('view engine', 'html');
    backend.set('view options', {
      layout: false
    });
    backend.use(express.bodyParser());
    backend.use(backend.router);
    backend.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  });
```

Lets say my site is running at localhost://mysite. I'm having to create all my route handlers as follows.

```
  backend.get('/mysite/index', function(req, res, next) {
    return res.render('index');
  });
```

i.e. I'm having to prefix them all with "mysite". Non of the examples I've seen require this. Is this something to do with IISNode or something else I haven't configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, this is indeed how you have to do it. You could look into [express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource), enabling resourceful routing - but that comes with it's own caveats, at least when it comes to route-specific middleware.

If it's just one path, I think you can handle that with `app.set("basepath", "mysite")`.

Comment: Thanks Linus, I'd didn't have any luck with app.set("basepath", "mysite"). I took a look at express-resource but I also found a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375554/is-it-possible-to-set-a-base-url-for-nodejs-app). In the end I went for  [express-namespace](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-namespace). It has [an issue in windows](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-namespace/issues/11) but is easily fixed by amending the index.js file in the express-namespace node_modules folder.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for this feature but for API routes, not for static files. What I did was that when I initialized the router, I added the mount path. So my configuration looks like this

```
//Default configuration
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.set('json spaces',0);
    app.use(express.limit('2mb'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    app.use('/api', app.router);        // <---

    app.use(function(err, req, res, callback){
        res.json(err.code, {});
    });
});
```

Notice the '/api' when calling the router

Comment: It worth to note that this solution works smoothly with express-resouce. I have several express subapps that provides an API below the prefix /api using this solution and a regular website at /.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to modify your express app when deploying in IIS using iisnode, you need to deploy to the root of the IIS WebSite rather than a virtual directory under a site.

Comment: I'm shocked at how many people think that suggesting a needless change to an entire application structure is the solution to this issue. This is the WORST possible answer shy of "it can't be done."