# Defaulting route to /api/:version in MEANJS

Tags: express, routes, meanjs

I am relatively new to [MEANJS](http://meanjs.org/), i have also been reading through its [documentation](http://meanjs.org/docs.html) to learn more.

so, i am trying to create a rest API using meanjs using its `yo generator` and removing the angular parts of it, so far it has been a success.

What i am trying to do now is to default the url routes to have a prefix of `/api/:version`, what i did so far is to append the `/api/:version` to the routes inside `app/` like the following

```
//app/routes/articles.server.routes.js 
'use strict';

...

module.exports = function(app) {
    // Article Routes
    app.route('/api/:version/articles')
    ...

    app.route('/api/:version/articles/:articleId')
    ...

    // Finish by binding the article middleware
    app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);
};
```

That works so far, but can i declared this somewhere so that i don't have to add `/api/:version` every time i create a new route?

I tried implementing [the ones stated in express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.route) and [Remi M's answer in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994334/387808) with no luck.

**Update**

meanjs installation comes with an `express.js`, so i thought that this is the right place to do it and i tried using the router object to solve this problem, although it doesn't work

```
//config/express.js
'use strict';
...
var express        = require('express');
...
var router         = express.Router();

module.exports = function(db) {
    var app = express();

    ...

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
        next();
    });

    app.use(compress({
        filter: function(req, res) {
            return (/json|text|javascript|css/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
        },
        level: 9
    }));

    ...

    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        if (!err) return next();
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500).render('500', {
            error: err.stack
        });
    });

    app.use(function(req, res) {
        res.status(404).render('404', {
            url: req.originalUrl,
            error: 'Not Found'
        });
    });

    ...

    app.use('/api/:version', router); //this is what i add

    return app;
};
```

Comment: express router is the right approach to solve this need. If you tried this and if it didn't work, post the relevant code snippet that is not working so we can help you debug the issue.

Comment: @PrabhuVelayutham i have updated the question with the relevant snippet, please check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your initial configurations should be on router object and not on app For Ex :

```
'use strict';
var express        = require('express');
var router         = express.Router();

module.exports = function(db) {
 var app = express();


router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
    next();
});

router.use(compress({
    filter: function(req, res) {
        return (/json|text|javascript|css/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
    },
    level: 9
}));

config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
    require(path.resolve(routePath))(router);
});
router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (!err) return next();
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).render('500', {
        error: err.stack
    });
});
router.use('/bar', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("bar endpoint called");
    res.send("bar");
});
router.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).render('404', {
        url: req.originalUrl,
        error: 'Not Found'
    });
});

  app.use('/api/:version/', router); //this is what i add

  return app;
};
```

Then call app.use("prefixurl",router) as above.

test the BAR API /api/v1/bar

Comment: tried this, i am afraid it doesn't work, please help

Comment: I commented out the config.getGlobbedFiles and created a custom route as below and confirmed that it is working. Give this custom route a try. router.use('/bar', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("bar endpoint called");
        res.send("bar");
    });

Comment: Here is the gist for the working code https://gist.github.com/pvela/560d8e7a044972041da2. Note that the app.use should have an ending slash and all the routes should start with a slash