# Express can't GET my external CSS, why?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, webstorm

Console always says : `GET http://localhost:8000/public/stylesheets/mystyle.css`.

Of course, as you will see in the attached below image, apparently it refers to an incorrect path. I used WebStorm itself to generate the `href` attribute of CSS.

**app.js**

```
var     express = require("express"),
            app = express(),
     bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
       mongoose = require ("mongoose");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

**header.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/stylesheets/mystyle.css" >
</head>
```

Project path : [image]

Comment: try remove "public" part from your uri

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak  "uri"? I don't know where you mean.

Comment: use like `/stylesheets/mystyle.css` instead of `../public/stylesheets/mystyle.css`

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak I'm getting crazy. No solution work. Pls say sth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express static directs your app to your static files for you (you have already taken care of that), try removing the public from your view url, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Blog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/mystyle.css" >
</head>
```

Comment: No unfortunately. The console now says: X GET http://localhost:8000/stylesheets/mystyle.css

Comment: @NorwayLover Does the get request have a 404 or 200?

Comment: @NorwayLover Can you share your folder/file structure?

Comment: @No unfortunately. Is there any further suggest? You can see the directory.

Comment: @NorwayLover try to change express.static to express.static('views/public')?

Comment: FINALLY THE PROBLEM SOLVED BY @Kudzai. Hey man I thank you very much for your great help 

Comment: @NorwayLover Cool

Answer (score 3):

You have a static relative path in (what I assume is) a HTML snippet/fragment shared by multiple pages in multiple directories in differing depths. I also assume "`public`" is the name given to the non-exposed root directory of your website. For this reason you should generally avoid the use of `../` relative paths in `href=""` and `src=""` attributes and instead use root-relative `/` or server-generated application-root URLs, also known as "base" URLs. (In ASP.NET this is done with `~/`. [Node.js does not currently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375554/is-it-possible-to-set-a-base-url-for-nodejs-app) have a built-in base URL feature, but there are third-party packages available that do this).

change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/stylesheets/mystyle.css" >
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/mystyle.css" >
```

As an aside, if your `styleseheets` directory contains only `*.css` files you should consider instead using a directory named `styles` which contains both `.css` files *and* other associated assets, like images and fonts that are referenced by the `.css` files, as this makes URLs in CSS shorter and without parent-relative paths, e.g.

```
foo#bar { background-image: url("../images/fooBg.png"); }
```

becomes:

```
foo#bar { background-image: url("fooBg.png"); }
```

Comment: No unfortunately. the console now says: X GET localhost:8000/stylesheets/mystyle.css. Why?

Comment: Please see the image again. Your solution doesn't solve the problem yet although I'm going to choose your answer as the best answer.

Comment: @NorwayLover I see you have your static files under your `Views` directory. I'm not too familiar with Node.js Express and how it exposes static files, so I cannot provide further assistance, sorry.

Comment: Oh, your answer was great and instructive. Nice to meet a precise dev like you! 

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers don't work, it might have something to do with the way you set the static directory with express. As mentioned in the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

> However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is
>   relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If
>   you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the
>   absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

That said, you may need to specify the absolute path to the public directory like so:

```
var path = require('path');
...


app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/mystyle.css" >
```

Comment: fyi, you have to do this alongside the proposed changes from the other answers