# How to add prefix to all node / express routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Does anyone know of a way to configure express to add a prefix before all routes automatically? for example, currently I have:

`/`

`/route1`

`/route2`

However, I want to add a prefix like:

`/prefix/`

`/prefix/route1`

`/prefix/route2`

Right now I need to define `prefix` manually to all of my routes but would like a more automated/configurable way. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375554/is-it-possible-to-set-a-base-url-for-nodejs-app but be careful to note which answers are for older versions of Express.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the express Router() for this.

You can use the router like you would use your express app. So for example:

```
const router = express.Router()
router.use(() => {}); // General middleware
router.get('/route1', () => {})
router.get('/route2', () => {})
router.post('/route2', () => {})
```

And then attach the router to your express app using:

```
app.use('/prefix', router);
```

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. However, it messed up my `res.render('...html')` (going to my route just has a blank screen now). Do you know if I need to re-configure how my static files are sent?

Comment: @TrungTran hard to tell without an error message. Could be that you're using relative paths and moved the file into a different directory

Comment: By doing this, its working for both API's. ie, works for `/prefix/route1` and `/route1`. How to restrict it for `/prefix/route1` only?

Comment: what if i want to add the same prefix to all of them?

Answer (score 11):

*routes.js*

```
module.exports = (app) => {
   app.post('/route', (req, res) => {
      res.status(status);
      res.send(data);
   }); 

   app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
      res.status(status);
      res.send(data);
   }); 

   return app; 
};
```

*Server.js*

```
const router = express.Router()
const routes = require('./routes')(router, {});
app.use('/PREFIX_HERE', routes)
```

REFER : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html